# Impex Error at referencing vm file

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am trying to create impex for email page.

$contentCatalog=ShopzoneContentCatalog
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged]

$jarResourceCms=jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/cockpits/cmscockpit/structure-view
$emailResource=jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/emails

$emailPackageName=com.shopzone.facades.process.email.context

## Email velocity templates

INSERT_UPDATE RendererTemplate;code[unique=true];description[lang=en];templateScript[lang=en,translator=de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.FileLoaderValueTranslator];contextClass;rendererType(code)[default='velocity']
;appointment_notification_email_subject;"Appointment Notification Email Subject";$emailResource/appointment_notification_email_subject.vm;$emailPackageName.AppointmentEmailContext;
;appointment_notification_email_body;"Appointment Notification Email Body";$emailResource/appointment_notification_email_body.vm;$emailPackageName.AppointmentEmailContext;

## Email page Template

INSERT_UPDATE EmailPageTemplate;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;active;frontendTemplateName;subject(code);htmlTemplate(code);restrictedPageTypes(code)
;;appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate;Appointment Notification Email Template;true;appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate;appointment_notification_email_subject;appointment_notification_email_body;EmailPage

## Templates for CMS Cockpit Page Edit

UPDATE EmailPageTemplate;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];velocityTemplate[translator=de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.FileLoaderValueTranslator]
;;appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate;$jarResourceCms/structure_appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate.vm

## Media

insert_update Media;code[unique=true];$contentCV;url;mime[default='image/jpg'];altText
;szEmailSiteLogoMedia;;/_ui/responsive/common/images/site_logo.png;;Shopzone

## CMS Image Components

INSERT_UPDATE CMSImageComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;media(code, $contentCV)
;;szEmailSiteLogoImage;Email Site Logo Image;szEmailSiteLogoMedia

## Content Slots

UPDATE ContentSlot;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];cmsComponents(uid,$contentCV)
;;szEmailSiteLogoSlot;szEmailSiteLogoImage

## Bind Content Slots to Email Page Templates

INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlotForTemplate;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];position[unique=true];pageTemplate(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true];contentSlot(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true];allowOverwrite
;;siteLogo-appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate;szSiteLogo;appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate;szEmailSiteLogoSlot;true

## Email Page

INSERT_UPDATE EmailPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;masterTemplate(uid,$contentCV);defaultPage;approvalStatus(code)[default='approved'];fromEmail[lang=en];fromName[lang=en]
;;appointmentNotificationEmailPage;Appointment Notification Email;appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate;true;;estore@shopzone.com;Customer Services Team

**ERROR :**

INSERT_UPDATE RendererTemplate;code[unique=true];description[lang=en];templateScript[lang=en,translator=de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.FileLoaderValueTranslator];contextClass;rendererType(code)[default='velocity']
,8796125836191,,, column 3: cannot resolve value 'jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/emails/appointment_notification_email_body.vm' for attribute 'templateScript', column 3: cannot resolve value 'jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/emails/appointment_notification_email_body.vm' for attribute 'templateScript';appointment_notification_email_body;Appointment Notification Email Body;jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/emails/appointment_notification_email_body.vm;com.shopzone.facades.process.email.context.AppointmentEmailContext;
,8796125868959,,, column 3: cannot resolve value 'jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/emails/appointment_notification_email_subject.vm' for attribute 'templateScript', column 3: cannot resolve value 'jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/emails/appointment_notification_email_subject.vm' for attribute 'templateScript';appointment_notification_email_subject;Appointment Notification Email Subject;jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/emails/appointment_notification_email_subject.vm;com.shopzone.facades.process.email.context.AppointmentEmailContext;

UPDATE EmailPageTemplate;catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog:Staged][unique=true];uid[unique=true];velocityTemplate[translator=de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.FileLoaderValueTranslator]
,8796420736052,,, column 3: cannot resolve value 'jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/cockpits/cmscockpit/structure-view/structure_appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate.vm' for attribute 'velocityTemplate', column 3: cannot resolve value 'jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/cockpits/cmscockpit/structure-view/structure_appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate.vm' for attribute 'velocityTemplate';;appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate;jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/resources/shopzonecore/import/cockpits/cmscockpit/structure-view/structure_appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate.vm

UPDATE ContentSlot;catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog:Staged][unique=true];uid[unique=true];cmsComponents(uid,catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog:Staged])
,,,no existing item found for update;;szEmailSiteLogoSlot;szEmailSiteLogoImage

INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlotForTemplate;catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog:Staged][unique=true];uid[unique=true];position[unique=true];pageTemplate(uid,catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog:Staged])[unique=true];contentSlot(uid,catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=ShopzoneContentCatalog:Staged])[unique=true];allowOverwrite
,,,error finding existing item : column='contentSlot' value='szEmailSiteLogoSlot', , column 5: could not resolve item for szEmailSiteLogoSlot;;siteLogo-appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate;szSiteLogo;appointmentNotificationEmailTemplate;szEmailSiteLogoSlot;true

02.11.2017 15:35:02: ERROR: Can not resolve any more lines ... Aborting further passes (at pass 2). Finally could not import 5 lines!
02.11.2017 15:35:02: ERROR: Can not resolve any more lines ... Aborting further passes (at pass 2). Finally could not import 5 lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference files, you need to reference them starting with the "resources" directory as your root directory.

$jarResourceCms=jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/import/cockpits/cmscockpit/structure-view $emailResource=jar:com.shopzone.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/shopzonecore/import/emails

Comment: will this reference work if run impex directly from hac ? is this a standard sytax for ref. to files in impex ? jar:qualifiedclassname&locationOfFile

Comment: from what I know an impex will have the same effect, whether it is ran via hac, or it is ran while updating the platform. So my answer would be yes.

Comment: Yes, it will work the same way. The reference is a reference to your classpath. The classpath includes the contents of all "rescources" directories.